# Swift, call generic function in another generic function

Tags: swift, generics

I pretty newbie in Swift (came from Java). I got quite a lot of headache while I was trying to call generic function from another generic function. More specifically I got standard error message: "Generic parameter T could not be inferred".
I assume that I may not know some language details, so hopefully someone can give me a solution, i.e. how I can correct this code to make it works:

```
//Second parameter is workaround for error no generic parameter in function signature    
func performRequest<T>(request: Request, stub: T?) -> Int {
    let result: T? = requestExecutor.execute(request)   
    return request.getId()
}
```

I've already spent quite a lot of time in Googling trying to figure out solution, but didn't found anything. I also tried to use T.Type instead of T? in parameters, but with no luck. I'm using Swift 2.2.1 in xCode 7.3.1.

Comment: Could you please provide a complete example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I'm an idiot. Thanks to comment of Sulthan I look to realization of of my RequestExecutor and I've realize that its execute have constraint on generics, i.e.

```
func execute<T: Mappable>(request: Request) ...
```

After change of function in my original post to

```
func performRequest<T: Mappable>(request: Request, stub: T?) -> Int...
```

all is working fine.
Sorry once again, I was way to concentrated on another part of code. Thanks to Sulthan for puting me on right track.
Hopefully this answer will be helpful for someone else :)